# How to use Angular 8 resolver with typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, resolve, angular-resolver

I am trying to make an application just like pastebin.com where i can use syntax highlight. Now i am trying to make the share file method. I am getting all the data from an .NET Core API, and the response are exactly what i need.

The problem is when i open the shared link the component gets initialized before the promise is resolved.

Let's say i want to open the following link: 
http://localhost:4200/shared/1

When i open the link, the data where the **file=1** is fetched and placed in a model. Then i want the component to be loaded and html displayed.

I don't understand how resolver work, what can i do ? Thanks.

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService implements Resolve<any> {

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
        console.log('Logging collected route parameter', route.params['file']);
        this.http.get(this.BaseURL + '/Share?IdentityString=' + route.params['file'])
        .subscribe(res =>{
        this.sharedFormData = res as ShareModel;

        console.log(this.sharedFormData);
    });
      }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'shared/:file',
    component: FileShareComponent,
    resolve: {
      shared: UserService
    }
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**fileshare.component.html**

```
export class FileShareComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: UserService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Component initialized');
  }
}
```

**fileshare.component.html**

```
<pre class="text-white"style="color: white;">Name: {{service.sharedFormData?.Name}}</pre>
<pre style="color: white;">Description: {{service.sharedFormData?.Description}}</pre>
<pre style="color: white;">Syntax: {{service.sharedFormData?.Syntax}}</pre>
<pre style="color: white;">LastModified: {{service.sharedFormData?.LastModified | date: "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy"}}</pre>
<pre style="color: white;">ExpirationDate: {{service.sharedFormData?.ExpirationDate | date: "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy"}}</pre>
<pre><code class="hljs">{{service.sharedFormData?.Content}}</code></pre>
```

This is how the URL looks:
http://localhost:4200/shared/MThBU1AgLk5FVCBDb3Jl

[image: Console log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the Observable/Promise in the `resolve()` method so that the HTTP request is finished before the component is initialized. Also note that you should not subscribe to the HTTP call in the `resolve()` method. Just return it as it is. If you want to log/store the data, use the `tap()` rxjs operator.

Modify your code as below:

**Resolver:**

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService implements Resolve<any> {

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
    console.log('Logging collected route parameter', route.params['file']);
    return this.http.
      get(this.BaseURL + '/Share?IdentityString=' + route.params['file'])
      .pipe(tap(res => console.log('Response from HTTP req: ', res)));
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```js
export class FileShareComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: UserService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Component initialized');
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: { shared: any }) => {
      let formData = data.shared as ShareModel;
      // perform your logic now
    });
  }
}
```

More information on resolver can be found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-angular-route-resolvers-by-example).